# How would you reshuffle this array efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binning, array-broadcasting

I have an array `arr_val`, which stores values of a certain function at large size of locations (for illustration let's just take a small one 4 locations). Now, let's say that I also have another array `loc_array` which stores the location of the function, and assume that location is again the same number 4. However, location array is multidimensional array such that each location index has the same 4 sub-location index, and each sub-location index is a pair coordinates. To clearly illustrate:

```
arr_val = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
loc_array = np.array([[[1,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2]],[[1,2],[2,4],[3,4],[4,1]], 
                     [[2,1],[1,4],[1,3],[3,3]],[[4,2],[4,3],[2,2],[4,4]]])
```

The meaning of the above two arrays would be value of some parameter of interest at, for example locations `[1,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2]` is `1`, and so on. However, I am interested in re-expressing the same thing above in a different form, which is instead of having random points, I would like to have coordinates in the following tractable form

```
coord = [[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]],[[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4]],[[3,1],[3,2], 
          [3,3],[3,4]],[[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,4]]]
```

and the values at respective coordinates given as

```
val = [[1, 2, 3, 3],[3, 4, 1, 2],[1, 1, 3, 2], [2, 4, 4, 4]]
```

What would be a very efficient way to achieve the above for large numpy arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lexsort` like so:

```
>>> order = np.lexsort(loc_array.reshape(-1, 2).T[::-1])
>>> arr_val.repeat(4)[order].reshape(4, 4)
array([[1, 2, 3, 3],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 3, 2],
       [2, 4, 4, 4]])
```

If you know for sure that loc_array is a permutation of all possible locations then you can avoid the sort:

```
>>> out = np.empty((4, 4), arr_val.dtype)
>>> out.ravel()[np.ravel_multi_index((loc_array-1).reshape(-1, 2).T, (4, 4))] = arr_val.repeat(4)
>>> out
array([[1, 2, 3, 3],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 3, 2],
       [2, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It could not be the answer what you want, but it works anyway.

```
val = [[1, 2, 3, 3],[3, 4, 1, 2],[1, 1, 3, 2], [2, 4, 4, 4]]
temp= ""
int_list = []

for element in val:
    temp_int = temp.join(map(str, element ))
    int_list.append(int(temp_int))

int_list.sort()
print(int_list)

## result ##
[1132, 1233, 2444, 3412]
```

- Change each `element` `array` into `int` and construct `int_list`
- Sort `int_list`
- Construct `2D np.array` from `int_list`

I skipped last parts. You may find the way on web.